# Posting a form multiple times with jQuery Deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I've been testing a bit with using $.Deferred() in jQuery lately and got a question. While deferred and promises are great for ajaxcalls that's only intended to run once, I also got a form for adding new users that posts with ajax needs to be runnable multiple times. Now this crashes with the binary(ish) state of a deferred/promise as once they're resolved or rejected it'll keep that state. So my questions are:

-Can I use deferred for a task that will be called multiple times?
-If possible, is it recommended to use deferred for this or should I stick to the old method with just using the success/error callbacks of $.ajax?

Here some code I got together for posting the form, which works great once, but not multiple times.

```
var submittingUser = new $.Deferred();
var savingUser = submittingUser.pipe(function(data) {
    return $.post('ajax.php', data);
});

$("#add_new_user").click(function() {
    var data = $("#add_user_form").serialize();
    submittingUser.resolve(data);
    return false;
});

savingUser.then(function() {
    //Success
}, function() {
    //Failed
});
```

Comment: I would revert back to using the direct approach. As you have found out, deferred objects cannot be resolved more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no sense to use a deferred in that manner. A deferred represents an action; you cannot use it as an event emitter. You use a deferred when you start an asynchronous action, and want to do something when that action succeeds or fails.

`$.post()` returns a promise (actually it returns a jqXHR instance, which however implements the promise interface), so you can do `$.post(...).fail(handleFailure).done(handleSuccess)`. But you cannot use a deferred to run some code every time something happens.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. Exactly what I wanted to know:)

Answer (score 2):

Deferred objects are once only by design, which allows one to add callbacks even after
a deferred has been resolved and get them fired.

From your code, it doesn't seem clear as why you can't just:

```
$("#add_user_form").submit( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post( "ajax.php", $(this).serialize() ).then( function(){

    }, function() {

    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. The code you post there will do the job just fine. My reason for asking was because I was curious as to whether deferred could be used also for handling repeatable tasks to keep my methods for doing ajax-calls as similar as possible. Thanks to great answers I now know I should stick with the old fashion way of submitting forms with either $.post or $.ajax

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic and the previous answers are a perfect solution to the original poster's problem, but I just came across the same general issue of trying to resolve deferred objects multiple times so I wanted to share a solution.

Even though the following is not possible:

```
var d = $.Deferred();
d.done(function(text){
   alert('resolved ' + text);
});
d.resolve('Once'); // prints resolved once
d.resolve('Twice'); // this does nothing as done is only fired once
```

You can achieve the exact same effect by just using the progress/notify functions of the jQuery Deferred object instead. Just do:

```
var d = $.Deferred();
d.progress(function(text){
   alert('resolved ' + text);
});
d.notify('Once'); // prints resolved once
d.notify('Twice'); // prints resolved twice
```

In this way, your deferred object is never truly resolved, but it will let you fire off as many asynchronous event calls as you want. Maybe it's not the best software design to solve the problem this way, but I found it useful for the situation that I just had.